# C# Run an External Game inside a panel and overlay a Label on the Screen

Tags: c#

I have a game "Project IGI" and I wanted to run the game inside a panel in C# and want to overlay a Label on the Game , as shown in the image....

[image: Game image]

I am new to programming so, I want the full source code for doing like this.
I had tried this :

```
`private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = Process.Start("IGI.EXE");
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // Allow the process to open it's window
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.BringToFront();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.BringToFront();
    }
}`
```

but unable to overlay a text on screen

please help me

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: Does the game show in the panel at all ?

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683): "it is technically legal. It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws... they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree"

Comment: That game I played 18 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

To overlay a label on the game screen, you can use the Graphics object and draw the label on top of it. Here is the code for that :

```
private Process gameProcess;
private String gameName = "igi.exe"; 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gameProcess = Process.Start(gameName);
    gameProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    gameProcess.Exited += GameProcess_Exited;
    gameProcess.WaitForInputIdle();

    SetParent(gameProcess.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
    MoveWindow(gameProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height, true);

    label1.Parent = panel1;
    label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    label1.AutoSize = true;
    label1.Location = new Point(panel1.Width / 2 - label1.Width / 2, panel1.Height / 2 - label1.Height / 2);
    label1.BringToFront();
}

private void GameProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        label1.Text = "Game Over";
        label1.Location = new Point(panel1.Width / 2 - label1.Width / 2, panel1.Height / 2 - label1.Height / 2);
        label1.BringToFront();
    });
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    label1.BringToFront();
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Refresh();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(label1.Text, label1.Font, new SolidBrush(label1.ForeColor), label1.Location);
}
```

Here's a brief explanation of the changes I made:

- Declare a Process variable to hold the game process.
- Set the game process to enable raising events and add an event
  handler for the process exited event.
- Wait for the game process to become idle before setting the parent
  and moving the window to the panel.
- Set the label's parent to the panel, set its background color to
  transparent, and position it in the center of the panel.
- Add the panel's Paint event handler to draw the label on top of the
  game screen using the Graphics object.
- When the game process exits, change the label text to "Game Over" and
  reposition it to the center of the panel.
- Call the label's BringToFront method in the MouseMove event handler
  to ensure it's always on top of the game screen.